# Inserting records for existing key in PyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo

I am trying to build a very simple REST API with backend as MongoDB. I am using Flask and Python to build the same. I just got confused on a part where I need to insert some records for an existing key.

Input :

```
stores =[
            {
                'name': 'My wonderful store',
                'items' : [
                            {
                                'name': 'My Item',
                                'price': 15.99
                            }
                        ]
            }
       ]
```

Now, if it would be normal dictionary , I could just append values where the key got matached, something like this :

```
def create_item_in_store(name):
    request_data = request.get_json()
    store = db.stores.find()
    for store in stores:
        if store['name'] == name :
            new_item ={
                'name': request_data['name'],
                'price':request_data['price']
            }
            **store[name].append(new_item)**
            return jsonify(new_item)
return jsonify({'message':'Store is not present'})
```

I tried to look into PyMongo documents but got confused with update syntax.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Updated my code using below logic and it's working as expected..

```
def create_item_in_store(name):
    request_data = request.get_json()
    stores = db.stores.find()
    for store in stores:
        print(store['name'])
        if store['name'] == name :
            new_item ={
                'name': request_data['name'],
                'price' : request_data['price']
            }
            db.stores.update_one({"name" : store['name']},{"$set": {"items" : [{"name" : request_data['name'], "price" : request_data['price']}]}})
            return jsonify(new_item)
    return jsonify({'message':'Store is not present'})
```